# Create clipping masks using contour lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, contour, vector-layer, vectorization

I'm new to QGIS and GIS in general. I'm trying to find a way to create height layers automatically and then use them to clip other layers.
In detail: Below is my area of interest. I have a raster containing height information and contourlines. I want to use the areas between the contour lines as clipping masks. Totally convex contours (like the small middle left) I can just fill with "convex enveloping" (I hope that's the English term for it). But others I can't. Especially the borders are difficult.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use the `GDAL > Raster Extraction > Contour Polygons` tool, which creates Multi-Polygons (closed by definition),  for each given contour line height.

DEM:
[image]

Contour Polygons:
[image]

You can then use features from the resulting Contour layer to clip other layers.